# Function creation at runtime in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
def fns(Names, Args, Bodies):
    for i in range(len(Names)):
        exec("def " + Names[i] + "(" + Args + "): " + Bodies[i])
```

All functions should be in the global scope, amount of calling code should not depend on number of functions.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I want to quickly create getters and setters for data structures made from lists. Specific fns() code doesn't matter much, it's about idea.

Comment: As others note, there is *definitely* a better way to do this. Creating global getters and setters for a data structure isn't the right choice in an OOC language anyway- just create a class.

Comment: There are several ways you could do this, but it depends on exactly what you're trying to acheive?  Can you give a complete example, showing examples of Names, Args and Bodies?  Off the top of my head, one way you could do this would be mess around with code objects, but there's probably a simpler and better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a good idea.. however

```
for i in range(len(Names)):
    exec("def " + Names[i] + "(" + Args + "): " + Bodies[i]) #create locally
    globals()[Names[i]] = locals()[Names[i]]                           #assign to global space
```

but I wouldn't recommend doing this... and that's untested code

Comment: Do you mean uppercase `names`? Also you are assigning `globals()[Names[i]]` to a string i think.

Comment: Yes: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: change it to `globals()[Names[i]] = locals()[Names[i]]`. Also I don't think you should be doing this as well, it is very hack-ish...

Comment: oops will fix now (should be locals()names[i])  ..... also I second @jamylak's opinion

Comment: Not sure as it depends on what you want to achieve using this.

Comment: make a generic function maybe or a subclass of list that has the getters and setters you want...  theres not very many good reasons I can think of for dynamic code like what your talking about...